# Powershell 5.1 in Windows 2012 R2

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, server, frameworks

I would like to install/upgrade powershell in my Windows 2012 R2 server.
As default w2k12 have 4.0 powershell so I've downloaded Windows Management Framework 5.1 as file: W2K12-KB3191565-x64.msu
When I run this - I'm getting error "The update is not applicable to your computer" - ok... researching google FOUND ...

I have to install full version of .NET Framework 4.5.2 - so ok.. Downloading dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe and RUN.

> Error: ""Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is already a part of this
>   operating system.  You do not need to install the .NET Framework 4.5
>   redistributable. Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4.5 has
>   already been installed on this computer.:"

OK trying install Developer Version NDP452-KB2901951-x86-x64-DevPack.exe

Trying check if FULL is installed -
`(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Version -like '4.5*'`
Still false

What is going on ?
Why its that hard install latest powerhsell 5.1 in Windows 2012 ? :/

Comment: Make sure that .NET 4.5 Features are enabled under `Server Manager` - `Manage`  - `Add Roles and Features`

Comment: all w2k12 have it enabled by default: http://oi68.tinypic.com/312e1j9.jpg

Comment: w2k12 is not the same as w2k12r2. You need  
`Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3191564-x64.msu`

Comment: Not necessarily. I have it blocked on one of our images due to some compatibility issues with older apps. Have you installed all available Windows Updates? @BenH , I didn't catch that. Nice!

Comment: @BenH - thanks for smart eyes I've lost 3 hours for .NET Framework .. and didnt look for good version of WMF installer Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3191564-x64.msu.  Many Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Get the update at: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616&ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-PY0rN6sxCyF8hlhQhRlodA&epi=TnL5HPStwNw-PY0rN6sxCyF8hlhQhRlodA&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2000142_aff_7593_1243925&tduid=(ir__biyzqumvw9kfrgvj0jd6oxxa1e2xjal2pedo1uo900)(7593)(1243925)(TnL5HPStwNw-PY0rN6sxCyF8hlhQhRlodA)()&irclickid=_biyzqumvw9kfrgvj0jd6oxxa1e2xjal2pedo1uo900

Then select the w2k 2012 R2 specific file name [image: PowerShell5.1 for w2k2012R2]:

Comment: I fell into the same trap, I think.  Downloaded W2K12-KB3191565-x64.msu and wondered why it didn't work.  I completely skipped over the correct download because it started with "Win8.1...".  I didn't notice the full name: Win8.1And**W2K12R2**-KB3191564-x64.msu.